# How to Poll to an external event listener from Salesforce

Tags: api

Hi All i need a recommendation on the approach. We have an backoffice home grown payment processing system. The requirement we got is when a payment got rejected in the processing system a case should be created in salesforce. The back office system is using event driven architecture so they are generating an event with payment ID to their event bus when a payment is rejected. Ask for our salesforce team is to subscribe to those events and get the payment Id and create a case accordingly. In Salesforce How can we subscribe for events generated by external systems?

Comment: Can they publish the same event in Salesforce Event Bus as well? We have event bus implementation.

Comment: So how is the "events" exposed to Salesforce? Does your external system have an API to consume that?

Comment: Nope pranay they are not going to publish to salesforce event bus

Comment: yes jayant they are going to have a event listener that we need to subscribe for

Comment: And how frequent your polling is expected to work? Like how frequent do they publish events in the scenario you have mentioned? Additionally, do they need a confirmation back when you have successfully created the Case record, how's the handshake expected?

Comment: Additionally, do you expect the event itself to contain all the details you want to create a Case or you need to again make another API call to get those details?

Comment: Wondering if you were able to find solution for this.